# Eclipse OnErrorListener cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listener

Something strange is happening. I want to put an ErrorListener on a VideoView. I had already did this with another project, but today I have this bug with Eclipse that doesn't enable me do this... I still get this error :

> OnErrorListener cannot be resolved as a type
>   The method setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener) in the type VideoView is not applicable for the arguments new OnErrorListener()

```
    import android.view.**View**;
    ...
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Of course I have closed Eclipse, rebooted twice. Maybe net reboot will be ok...

Answer (score 1):

You either did not import `OnErrorListener` or you have the wrong imports.

Comment: well thanks. So easy... I thought it was automatic... It is in android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener